# How to adjust Bootstrap's container div to 100px off the left viewport edge?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap fixed layout where the container `div` has:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

So it always stays in the center.

What I want to do is position the container so that there is a 100px gap between the left browser window border and the container. When the window gets smaller I want the container move to border of the window.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I did:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 250px;
}
```

doesn't give me exactly the result I was looking for, but pretty close. My first span 3 is a sidebar and the last span9 main content area. The main content area is now always centered and the sidebar next to it and has a minimum gap of 10px to the window border.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to changing the margins of the container is to use `container-fluid` an only use 8 (or 10) of the 12 columns on larger screens...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
         .. page layout here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/SRnhM22tPr

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting the twitter bootstrap css file's `.container` to have `margin-left: 100px` solves the problem of positioning it closer.

As for moving it closer when the window gets smaller, I have no idea how it could be done with css so that the maximum is 100px. But without the maximum it is doable with `margin-left: x%` where x is the number you see fit. That way when the browser window size changes, so does the left margin.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yea I tested that too. But the problem really is that I want it to move to the border as soon as the window size hits the border of the container content

Comment: you'll have to use something like jquery for that and the modify the css walue of the `margin-left`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fluid layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) and add padding to the body.

```
body { padding-left: 100px; }
```

That way the content will always fill the window up to 100px from the left hand side.

Comment: I don't really want to use the fluid layout. Just the 940px container with the correct adjusted postition

Comment: Why?  What you're asking for is the very definition of fluid. "When the window gets smaller I want the container move to border of the window."

Comment: Got it now ;) used a simple media query

Comment: Cool, just be aware that IE6,7 & 8 don't support them.  But those users should be cursed anyways :)