# What do I need to do to get these bootstrap columns to align left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web template that I am using with a top and left nav and I want to have the three column elements left aligned. Even in a [simple example](http://www.bootply.com/64RgcMF0dc#), the columns want to be center aligned.

Can anyone tell me how to get the columns to snuggle up to the left margin?

*disclaimer - I am Learning Bootstrap so my ability to answer this myself is probably limited by my Bootstrap vocabulary.

I tried searching a bunch of different ways and settle don this as the most relevant search query: 
bootstrap left align columns -nav -navbar

That search produced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266175/how-do-i-left-align-these-bootstrap-form-items) answer, but it didn't seem to solve my problem, or I didn't do it right.

I have created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/64RgcMF0dc#) that simulates my problem so if anyone wants to try it out, they can.

Comment: You mean not on the left like this? http://www.bootply.com/SRnhM22tPr

Comment: Or like this? http://www.bootply.com/FMrwn31QDc

Comment: Yes! If I follow your changes correctly, all you did was change the div class at the top to container-fluid from container and change the outermost column side from col-md-12 to col-md-8. Is that correct?

Comment: @GeorgeLee - Not like that. I want the columns all side by side, but I wanted them left aligned in the container. ZimSystem got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left align the container as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102446/twitter-bootstrap-css-container-position), or simply use a full-width `container-fluid`, and then only use a portion of the 12 Bootstrap columns, for example 8 columns..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
         .. page layout here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/SRnhM22tPr

On smaller screens you'd probably want the layout to be full-width instead of left aligned.

Comment: Just so I am clear, container-fluid could be construed as container-left-aligned-with-wrapping-on-smaller-devices, yes?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know. I'd construe it as only-using-the-left-portion-of-full-width-container on large screens

Answer (score 0):

in your main div (page-wrapper), change the class from container, to container-fluid.

```
<div id="page-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
```

and you should see those elements all with left alignment.

Comment: I could swear I tried that :( I read the [docs on containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) and I still don't understand why this fixed it?