# Boost strap Grid system

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

I have some experience with Jsx and today I was looking at a react project. hoping I can make some changes to the style. thinking it's like react-native, but it had bootstrap and I coulden't wrap my head around it even after spending an hour on their website.

I just wanted move a container to the left. which I thought is simple but it so tedious with bootstrap.
`<div className="container" >`

how about the styling below? what does that even mean. how do I decipher that?
`<div className="shadow component rounded p-5 col-sm-10 col-md-6 mt-4">`

anyone here have a quick cheat sheet or nice tutorial to share, and maybe can give me a quick fix on how to move that container left for now while I try to learn more of bootstrap or maybe depreciate it completely idk.

```
render() {
    return (
***//this box is in middle of the screen and I want to push it a little to the left***.
        <div className="container" > 
          <Notifications />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="shadow component rounded p-5 col-sm-10 col-md-6 mt-4">
              <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <h1 className="h3 text-center mb-3 font-weight-normal h1" 
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can refer Bootstrap Gridsystem in detail here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/
Also this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102446/how-to-adjust-bootstraps-container-div-to-100px-off-the-left-viewport-edge
If these doesnt help. Please add more detail the whole container. What will be on left and what on right.

Comment: I already check both those places and it did not work for me. I am going to add a spinet of code.

Answer (score 0):

No need to "decipher" it if you get the idea and actually it's really simple.

Bootstrap is basically a CSS **framework** that contains CSS templates for typography, forms, buttons, and other interface components.

For example:
by adding `shodow` class to your div, it refers to a pre-defined CSS style:

```css
.shadow {
   box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15)!important;
}
```

If you add `rounded` class that will add more CSS:

```css
.rounded {
   border-radius: .25rem!important;
}
```

And so on .. it's just about shorting the time so you don't need to write the code yourself.

Here is a free online course: [Bootstrap Beginner Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GcQtLDGXy)

---

Back to your main question.. First, please make sure that you already have Bootstrap in your react project, If done, no need to move the whole `container` Bootstrap 4 grid system is using [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp) by default and `row` class already have `display: flex;` so you can just use `auto margins` inside `row` children divs.  See the example:

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="p-2 border">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 border">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 border ml-auto">Left Flex item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How auto margins works?**

> Flexbox can do some pretty awesome things when you mix flex alignments with auto margins. Shown below are three examples of controlling flex items via auto margins: default (no auto margin), pushing two items to the right (.mr-auto), and pushing two items to the left (.ml-auto). [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#auto-margins)

So, in your case you just need to add **ml-auto** class to your **component** div:

```
<div className="shadow component rounded p-5 col-sm-10 col-md-6 mt-4 ml-auto"></div>
```